# Filtering a Matrix block for future dates

Tags: matrix, search

I'm struggling with filtering future dates in a Matrix block that contains a date field.

I would like to display 'Open' or 'Closed' as the result of a condition checking if the value of matrix rows is today, but I only want to run the condition against future dates in the matrix block.  Past dates should be ignored.

In all examples I have seen, the search logic is at declared at the entries-level, but this is a matrix block and I can't get the two to connect.

My code...

````
{% set closed = craft.block('closedDates')
    .type('closedDate')
    .date('>=' ~ today)
    .all() %}
{% for block in entry.closedDates.all() %}
    {% if today == closed %}
        <p><strong>Closed</strong></p>
    {% else %}
        <p>Open</p>
    {% endif %}
{% endfor %}```

The (matrix) field = closedDates, the block type = closedDate, the field = date.

I prefer a matrix field so I have only 1 entry.

Would appreciate any suggestions.
````

Comment: Your matrix field consists of a date and you set the date as a "closed date" right? So block.date is the date where it is closed?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Thanks Marten, yes, that's correct.

After plugging away I have gotten it to work, but it's likely not as efficient as it could be...

```
{% set today = now|date('Y-m-d') %}
{% set todayday = now|date('l') %}
{% for block in entry.closedDates.date('>=' ~ today).limit(1) %}
    {% set closedDate = block.date.format('Y-m-d') %}
    {% if closedDate == today %}
        <p><strong>It's a holiday, sorry, we're closed</strong></p>
    {% elseif todayday == 'Sunday' %}
        <p><strong>It's {{ todayday }}, sorry, we're closed</strong></p>
    {% else %}
        <p>We're Open!</p>
    {% endif %}
{% endfor %}
```

I added a check for whether today is Sunday, which is a normally closed day that would not be in the entry.

Doug